# Create a new folder on a server with php

Tags: java, php, android

I have an Android program that upload a file to a php server, but I need to create a folder in the php server with the name provided by the Android program.

For example, if I want to create a folder called "John" in my server, first I have to pass this name (John) through the `HttpURLConnection` to my server but I don't know how.

This is my Android code:

```
package com.myapplication.uploadtoserver;

/**
 * Created by administrador on 4/6/15.
 */

import java.io.DataOutputStream;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.Environment;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class UploadToServer extends Activity {

TextView messageText;
Button uploadButton;
int serverResponseCode = 0;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;

String upLoadServerUri = null;

/**********  File Path *************/

final String uploadFileName = "service_lifecycle.png";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_to_server);

    uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);

    messageText.setText("Uploading file path :"+ "/storage/sdcard1"+"/"+uploadFileName+"'");

    /************* Php script path ****************/
    upLoadServerUri = "http://192.168.1.131/UploadToServer.php";

    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                        }
                    });

                    uploadFile("/storage/sdcard1" + "/" + uploadFileName);

                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
}

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


    //String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        dialog.dismiss();

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                +"/storage/sdcard1" + "/" + uploadFileName);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                        +"/storage/sdcard1" + "/" + uploadFileName);
            }
        });

        return 0;

    }
    else
    {
        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

/*****************I THINK MY DOUBT IS IN THIS PART OF THE CODE***************/

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", sourceFileUri);
            //I THINK THAT HERE SHOULD BE A FUNCTION TO SEND THE NAME OF THE FOLDER TO MY SERVER
            //BUT I DON'T KNOW WHICH ONE IS. SOMETHING LIKE conn.setRequestProperty("my_directory", "John");

/****************************************************************************/

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_file;filename="
                            + sourceFileUri + "" + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                +uploadFileName;

                        messageText.setText(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                    + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block
  }
}
```

My script PHP (`UploadToServer.php`):

```
$file_path = "/opt/lampp/htdocs/uploads/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

Comment: why dont you try`conn.setRequestProperty("file_name", "your_file_name");` in android and retrieve the value sent using `$fname=$_GET["file_name"];` ?

Comment: Just I want retrieve a String value and create a new directory in my server with that String value. 

My Android Code:
`conn.setRequestProperty("dni_directory", "12345678A");`


My PHP code:

`<?php

    $new_directory=$_GET["dni_directory"];
    $path="opt/lampp/htdocs/uploads/";
    $directory=$path . $new_directory;
    
    mkdir($directory, 0777);

 ?>`  But it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `echo $new_directory;` in your PHP code and check if the correct value is obtained.

Comment: How I can see my PHP server? What I want is see the screen where is printed `echo $new_directory`